# Isomorphism of algebras in Artin-Wedderburn theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

In Erdmann and Holm's book *Algebras and representation theory*, we have the following two lemmas.

**Lemma 5.5.** Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra. Given finitely many $A$-modules $U_1, \dots , U_r,$
we consider $r \times r$-matrices whose $(i, j )$-entry is an A-module homomorphism from
$U_j$ to $U_i$:
$$\Lambda = \left\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} 
\varphi_{11} & \cdots & \varphi_{1r}\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
\varphi_{r1} & \cdots & \varphi_{rr}
 \end{pmatrix}\ \Big|\ \varphi_{ij} \in \mathrm{Hom}_A (U_i, U_j) \right\rbrace$$

Then $\Lambda$ becomes a K-algebra with respect to matrix addition and matrix multipli-
cation, where the product of two matrix entries is composition of maps.

**Lemma 5.6.** Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra, suppose $U_1, \dots , U_r$ are $A$-modules and
$V := U_1 \oplus \dots \oplus U_r$, their direct sum. Then the algebra $\Lambda$ from Lemma 5.5 is isomorphic as a $K$-algebra to the endomorphism algebra $\mathrm{End}_A (V)$.

My question is: are the algebras from lemma 5.6. also isomorphic as $A$-algebras (and would that imply isomorphism as $K$-algebras)? In particular, I'm curious where the proof for $K$-isomorphism would fail.